# Express not serving entire static directory just index.html

Tags: javascript, express, static-files

My file structure is as follows:

```
src
  |- client
      |- js
        |- test.js
      |- index.html
  |- server
      |- server.js
```

What I want to serve is the whole client folder. So on`/` I should render index.html and also serve the js folder when I hit the `/` route i.e just `localhost:3000` in this example

My server.js file is as follows:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var path = require('path');

app.use(express.static(path.resolve(__dirname + '/../client')));

app.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log('listening on: ', 3000);
})
```

I end up rendering the index.html file correctly but I do not receive the rest of the files/folders in the client directory.

Comment: So requesting `http://localhost:3000/js/test.js` yields a 404 (Not Found) error?

Comment: So sorry I misspelled my script tag in the index.html which did not allow my scripts to load. Thanks

Comment: In that case, feel free to close your question :)

Answer (score 1):

I had my script tag as minimized i.e `<script src="js/test.js />`. This does not allow for the rest of the folder to load. I changed it to `<script src="js/test.js></script>`